# how to align right hand side image on top of text on mobile screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive-design

I have two rows on a webpage: on the first row, the image is on left side and text on right side. For the second row, it's vice versa. When I see the page on a mobile device, the image which is on the left goes on top of the text and the image on the right side goes to the bottom of the text.

I want all images to be at  the top of the text, whether it is on the right or the left side of the screen.

How should I do that?

**HTML code**

```
<section class="pagecontent first_row" id="pagecontent">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 text-center animated wow fadeInLeft">
                <div class="iphone1">
                    <img src="images/image1.png" alt="" titl="">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-7 animated wow fadeInRight">
                <div class="features_list1">
                    <h1 class="text-uppercase">Text on Right</h1>
                    <p>Some text</p>
                </div>                  
            </div>
        </div>
    <hr class="style3">
    </div>
</section>

<section class="pagecontent second_row" id="pagecontent">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7 animated wow fadeInLeft">
                 <div class="features_list1">
                     <h1 class="text-uppercase">Text on Left</h1>
                     <p>Some text</p>
                </div>  
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-5 text-center animated wow fadeInRight">
                <div class="iphone1">
                    <img src="images/image2.png" alt="" titl="">
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr class="style3">
    </div>
</section>
```

Some CSS code

```
.pagecontent .iphone1{
    max-width: 359px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.pagecontent .iphone1 img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
 .pagecontent .features_list1 p{
    color: #767272;
    font-family: "open_regular", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 19px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

Any help would be useful.

Comment: It would be better if you include some code. Without your page structure, it would be hard to answer

Comment: @abhishekkannojia I have added the html code. please check.

Comment: If your requirement is just that image should be on the top of text in case of mobile screens you can simply move the your `div` containing `image2` before the text `div`. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5w4rafwp/)

Comment: @abhishekkannojia yeah, but I want that image which is on right side on desktop that should go to top of text on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`col-push-*` and `col-pull-*` can help you

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 text-center animated wow fadeInRight col-md-push-7">
  <div class="iphone1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" titl="">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-7 animated wow fadeInLeft col-md-pull-5">
  <div class="features_list1">
    <h1 class="text-uppercase">Text on Left</h1>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see that in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Narek_T/aq8oaevg/)

Comment: I was unknown about `col-push-* ` and `col-pull-*` css of bootstrap. I got your point and I have adjusted my html to get desired result. Thanks a lot for the help :)